# Visual Studio properties Panel Refreshing/flashing

Tags: properties, visual-studio-2013

Not STRICTLY a coding issue, more of Visual Studio Issue.

When creating a new project -any project- when i open the properties panel, it keeps 'flashing'. Even when i drag a button onto a winform/etc, and press F4. It will continue to flash at regular intervals.

Due to this 'refresh', I am unable to rename/change text/etc using the panel, as each time i click into the 'Name' / Text' / etc, it will flash and hence loose focus.

As a workaround, I am currently writing my variable's name into word, copying it, and then trying to quickly paste it into the panel before it refreshes again.

Has anyone else come across this issue, or have been able to solve this?

Cheers

Comment: Quirky behavior like this is almost always caused by a mis-behaving add-in.  Disable them one-by-one until you find the troublemaker.

Comment: I was thinking that just now actually. it only seemed to start when i installed dev express (i think) - but completely removed it, and had same problem. So reinstalled (i'm using it currenlty in most projects) and will see if disabling any of the others works